# running `print(sys.platform)` in the plain Python interpreter yielded a blank string

Tags: pip, python-3.5, sys, platform, ansi-escape

Running `print(sys.platform)` in the plain Python interpreter yielded a blank string

I try to configure the code of an open source python project on github..I installed the program with pip install and it worked perfectly. However, in order to make changes to the code I had to use the pip install -e command in order to enable editable installations. When I run the program this time it looked like my terminal didn’t interpreting ANSI color escape sequences, and that the detection that turns them off on Windows wasn’t working.

I then run `print(sys.platform)` in the plain Python interpreter and I got back a blank string.
Is there a way to fix this problem with the Python setup of my machine??
I run windows 10 64bit and python 3.5

Comment: So, I would assume that `print(repr(sys.platform))` gives `''`?

Comment: What is `sys.__file__`? Any chance this project has its own sys module?! Does starting a new console help? Or logout/login?

Comment: It might be useful to mention your OS setup. Which Windows version do you have? Which Python version? How did you install Python? Etc.

Comment: No, it just returns an empty line, not ''

Comment: If `print(repr(sys.platform))` gives an empty line, then something is seriously, gravely wrong.

Comment: Can you tell me the exact command to paste in the cmd? Just to be 100% I did it right

Comment: Can you post the url to this project?

Comment: https://github.com/beetbox/beets

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce (Windows10/Python 3.5):

```
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.platform
'win32'
>>>
```

Maybe something wrong with your installation ?

Comment: In the python command promt if I type print(sys.platform) I get win32. In the normal cmd I get an empty line..And the ansi coloring problems with the developers installation of the program ramain.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "python command prompt" versus "normal cmd"?

Comment: Python 3.6(32bit) application...It looks like the classic cmd but you can run python directly from there

Comment: I am sorry but I always get 'win32': from the command line, from IDLEX shell, from IPython and from Spyder